# How to run standard SQL query in BigQuery PySpark stored procedure

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, stored-procedures, apache-spark-sql, google-bigquery

I run the following PySpark stored procedure in Bigquery;

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("work_with_sql").getOrCreate()

df = spark.sql(
'''
SELECT tag, COUNT(*) c
FROM (
     SELECT SPLIT(tags, '|') tags
     FROM `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_questions` a
     WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM creation_date)>=2024
     ), UNNEST(tags) tag
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 2 DESC
LIMIT 10
'''
)

df.show()
spark.stop()
```

but it says in the logging;

```
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: Table or view not found: `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_questions`; line 5 pos 9;
```

How can I use spark.sql in PySpark stored procedure?

Answer (score 0):

`spark.sql` is used to query data in the Spark context. To load data from a BigQuery query you can use:

```py
spark.conf.set("viewsEnabled","true")
spark.conf.set("materializationDataset","<dataset>")

sql = """
  SELECT tag, COUNT(*) c
  FROM (
    SELECT SPLIT(tags, '|') tags
    FROM `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_questions` a
    WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM creation_date)>=2014
  ), UNNEST(tags) tag
  GROUP BY 1
  ORDER BY 2 DESC
  LIMIT 10
  """
df = spark.read.format("bigquery").load(sql)
df.show()
```

More details in the docs: https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/spark-bigquery-connector?tab=readme-ov-file#reading-data-from-a-bigquery-query

Comment: It is giving error in Bigquery UI as;  Syntax error: Expected end of input but got keyword SELECT at [8:3]

Answer (score 0):

code like this will work:

```
def main():
    sql = 'select date,ctr from `{PROJECT_NAME}.{DATA_SET_NAME}.{TABLE_NAE}`'

    df = spark.read \
        .format("bigquery") \
        .load(sql)
    df.show()
    # 停止 SparkSession
    spark.stop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    from pyspark import SparkConf
    from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

    # 初始化spark框架
    conf = SparkConf(). \
        setAppName(f"spark-bq"). \
        set("parentProject", '{PROJECT_NAME}'). \
        set("credentialsFile", '/home/admin/tso_test/truemetrics-lilysilk-cdp-3efdaf581a57.json'). \
        set("materializationDataset", "{DATA_SET_NAME}"). \
        set("viewsEnabled", True)

    spark = SparkSession.builder.enableHiveSupport(). \
        config(conf=conf).getOrCreate()

    main()
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.